# Finding Lagrangian with Non-holonomic constraints

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am stuck working on a problem that involves finding the Lagrangian for a free particle constrained to move on the surface of a disk of radius $a$. The particle collides elastically with the edge of the disk. I have tried the standard method of multipliers, but that doesn't work. Is there a way to convert this non-holonomic constraint into a holonomic one?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, cool problem. At each collision with the wall, $v_{r}=\dot{r}$ flips sign but $\dot{\theta}$ stays the same, and thus so does the angular momentum $L$. No idea if this works, but it seems worth a shot - I was inspired by quantum mechanics. You basically have a particle in a well. So
\begin{align}
L &= T-V\\
&= \frac{1}{2}mv^{2} - V\\
&= \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^{2}+r^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2}) - V(r)
\end{align}
where 
$V(r) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } r<a \\
\infty & \mbox{if } r\geq a \end{cases}$. You could possibly write $$V=V_{0}\Theta(r-a)$$ and then send $V_{0}\rightarrow\infty$, where $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Are you sure about the Heaviside step function version?

Comment: Sure about it in the sense...? Oh you mean having the $\theta(r)$ term. As $V_{0}\rightarrow\infty$ it's not a problem, as it enforces the $r\geq 0$ condition. I've found it useful in electrostatics where it helps me remember the Dirac delta from the divergence of $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$.  But I see your point, I'll edit to include the more traditional version.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear, was I. I meant that should it not be just $V = V_0\Theta(r-a)$?

Comment: Ha, I completely missed that! So used to stuff being in solid spheres, I forgot which part was zero! Thanks, fixed, finally.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar with KKT conditions. I wanted to see if this would work instead of the potential trick you did. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/328129/lagrangian-and-kkt-constraint-for-falling-ball-with-a-floor