# Lagrangian and KKT Constraint for Falling Ball with a Floor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, variational-calculus

I am trying to use [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) and [slack variables (pg. 118)](http://adl.stanford.edu/aa222/Lecture_Notes_files/chapter5_constrainopt.pdf) to put a floor constraint into my Lagrangian for a falling ball with a floor.

\begin{align}
\text{extrem}\ \ &\int dt\ \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - mgx \\
\text{s.t.}\ \ &x \ge 0
\end{align}

This can be written with a Lagrange multiplier $ \lambda $ and slack variable $ s $ like,
\begin{align}
S &= \int dt\ \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - mgx + \lambda(x - s^2) \\
\delta S &= \int dt\ (- m \ddot{x} - mg + \lambda) \delta x + \delta \lambda(x - s^2) - 2\lambda s \delta s
\end{align}
where I made the boundary conditions vanish like normal.

Thus I am left with 3 equations, which need to be reduced, being careful to keep $ s $ real, $ \lambda/m = \mu $
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} = -g + \mu,\ \ x &= s^2, \ \ s \lambda = 0 \\
2(\dot{s}^2 + s \ddot{s}) &= -g + \mu\\
s \mu &= 0
\end{align}

I see two cases. $ s \ne 0 $ and $ s = 0 $.

For $ s \ne 0 $ then $ \mu = 0 $,
$$
\dot{s}^2 + s \ddot{s} = -g/2
$$

For $ s = 0 $, then $ \mu $ need not be zero,

\begin{align}
2(\dot{s}^2 + s \ddot{s}) &= -g + \mu \\
\dot{s} &= \sqrt{\frac{\mu - g}{2}}
\end{align}

For $ s \in \mathbb{R} $, $ \mu \ge g $. Looking at what $ \mu $ does physically, this makes sense. It cancels the gravity out when the ball hits the floor, and further more permits a rebound effect.

Unfortunately, I don't see how, from this method, to get the what $ \mu $ should be exactly. Is there anyway I can get the exact value for $ \mu $? Its not obvious from here that the ball should rebound, although rebound is permitted thus far mathematically.

Comment: I've been thinking about solving this by choosing $ \mu $ such that the Hamiltonian energy is conserved. Unfortunately, this would seems to demand that $ \mu = -\dot{x} \delta(x) $ or something similar so that when I integrate over it, it delivers an impulse to my system to conserve energy, but maintain the constraint. I don't like sticking delta functions in by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hamiltonian is,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H} = \frac{p^2}{2} + gx - \mu(x - s^2)
\end{align}

We claim that the Hamiltonian must not change after the collision

\begin{align}
0 &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \mathcal{H}(x(t), p(t)) - \mathcal{H}(x(t+\epsilon), p(\epsilon)) \\
  &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{p(t)^2 - p(t + \epsilon)^2}{2} + g(x(t) - x(t + \epsilon)) - \mu(t)(x(t) - s(t)^2) + \mu(t+\epsilon)(x(t+\epsilon) - s(t+ \epsilon)^2) \right]
\end{align}

Let $ x(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} x(t+\epsilon) = 0 $ in accordance with the case we wish to solve for, then

\begin{align}
0 &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{p(t)^2 - p(t + \epsilon)^2}{2} \right]
\end{align}
because $ s^2 = x $.

From Hamilton's equations we get,
\begin{align}
\dot{p} &= \mu - g \\
p(t+\epsilon) - p(t) &= \int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) - g \\
p(t+\epsilon)^2 &= p(t)^2 + 2p(t)\left[-\epsilon g + \int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) \right] + \left[-\epsilon g + \int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) \right]^2 \\
\end{align}

Thus, we get,
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[ p(t)^2 - p(t + \epsilon)^2 \right] &= - 2p(t) \int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) - \left[\int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) \right]^2 \\
2p(t) \int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) &= -\left[\int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) \right]^2 \\
\int_t^{t+\epsilon} dt\ \mu(t) &= -2p(t)
\end{align}

Or, as could have been guessed,
\begin{align}
\mu(t) = -2p(t)\delta(x(t))
\end{align}